# How to use Socks5 with fsockopen in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, fsockopen, socks

I want to be able to connect to a remote host (e.g FTP, SMTP, POP) through Socks5 using [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen) in PHP.

Please how do I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fsockopen` just opens a socket connection. You should manually create request packets and parse responses to implement `Socks5` since there is no built-in support in PHP. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) to know how Socks5 works.

Alternatively you can use something like [this SOCKS 5 class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1822-PHP-TCP-connection-wrapper-using-SOCKS-5-protocol.html).

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Checked the Socks5 Class and I think it should serve the purpose. One more thing, what would the headers be like if I were to be connecting to a SMTP Server or FTP Server?

Comment: SMTP and FTP requests through SOCKS5 are just like the regular requests, but you should first connect and authenticate to the `Socks5` server, send a connect command with the host address of your FTP or SMTP server and once you receive `connected` response packet from socks server, you can send ordinary FTP or SMPT requests.

Comment: Thanks once again. Will I just send `CONNECT ftp.server.com` or `CONNECT smtp.server.com` alone?